# How does the NAD+/NADH ratio affect lifespan in vertebrates?

Tags: senescence

Here's the proximate physical implication of the ratio (from the Wikipedia article on NADH).

> The balance between the oxidized and reduced forms of nicotinamide
>   adenine dinucleotide is called the NAD+/NADH ratio. This ratio is an
>   important component of what is called the redox state of a cell, a
>   measurement that reflects both the metabolic activities and the health
>   of cells. The effects of the NAD+/NADH ratio are complex,
>   controlling the activity of several key enzymes, including
>   glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate dehydrogenase and pyruvate dehydrogenase.
>   In healthy mammalian tissues, estimates of the ratio between free NAD+
>   and NADH in the cytoplasm typically lie around 700; the ratio is thus
>   favourable for oxidative reactions. The ratio of total
>   NAD+/NADH is much lower, with estimates ranging from 0.05 to 4. In
>   contrast, the NADP+/NADPH ratio is normally about 0.005, so NADPH is
>   the dominant form of this coenzyme. These different ratios are key
>   to the different metabolic roles of NADH and NADPH.

So here's my question: how does this manifest in vertebrate aging? Is it something that's simply the resultant of other aging processes, or can the ratio also contribute to aging in a certain way?

Comment: What's the source of this quote?

Comment: Wikipedia (have added a note for clarification).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This study](http://dx.doi.org/%20doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0019194) found a statistically significant decline in NAD+:NADH ratios and in intracellular NAD+ with age in the organs of rats.

They discuss that the activation of  PARP - the  NAD-dependent enzyme Poly(ADP-ribose) polymerase-1 instrumental in DNA repair - increases in aging organs (heart, liver, kidneys). This depletes cellular NAD+ levels via poly(ADP-ribosylation) of proteins. This reduced cellular  NAD+ then reduces the effectiveness of Sirtuins (Sirt1) which can [deacetylate tumor-suppressor proteins such as p53.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12220851)

Here's schematic showing the basic idea from their figure 10:

[image]

So, the inference is that oxidative stress in vertebrates increases with age due to lowered cellular NAD+ - i.e.,  consistent with the free-radical theory of aging.  This could mean that lowered cellular NAD+, NAD+/NADH in any given individual may well decrease said individuals lifespan.

The authors of the first study (Braidy et al 2011) suggest that therapies involved in maintaining high NAD+ levels may alleviate age-associated disorders.

- [Braidy N, Guillemin GJ, Mansour H, Chan-Ling T, Poljak A, et al. (2011) Age Related Changes in NAD+ Metabolism Oxidative Stress and Sirt1 Activity in Wistar Rats. PLoS ONE 6(4)](http://dx.doi.org/%20doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0019194)
- [Smith, J., (2002) Human Sir2 and the 'silencing' of p53 activity, Traneds, Cell Biol. 12, 404](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12220851)